# Compare models using residuals

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, residuals, model-comparison

Is it statistically correct to compare two models using their residuals? For example, I have two dose-response models, then am comparing their residuals and concluding they are not statistically different

```
library(drc)
ryegrass.m1 <- drm(rootl ~ conc, data = ryegrass, fct = W1.4())
a <- residuals(ryegrass.m1)
ryegrass.m2 <- drm(rootl ~ conc, data = ryegrass, fct = LL.5())
b <- residuals(ryegrass.m2)
t.test(a,b)
```

Then conclude that the two dose-response curves or models are not different from the t-test results?

Answer (score 1):

You could well base a model comparison on residuals, for instance residual sum square RSS is a function of residuals.  But not in the way you are doing it, a `t.test` comparing residuals. The t test will compare the mean of the residuals, but that will always be zero (least squares) or approximately zero (more general maximum likelihood), so the t test will **never** reject, so is not useful for comparing models.

Model comparison based on residuals would have to be based on some other function of residuals than means, such as RSS mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the L1 or L2 error functions. The L1 function is the sum of the absolute values of the differences and the L2 function is the sum of the squares of the differences. The L1 function prioritizes creating more very small differences and the L2 function prioritizes creating less very large differences.

[image]